# how to improve CPUs performance on a laptop

Tags: cpu, performance

I have an HP EliteBook 8540w Mobile Workstation with Intel Core i7, 4GB RAM, 500GB of HDD storage and Windows 10. If I am doing a video conference,  the CPU maxes out sometimes and i want to improve that. does anybody have a solution for this? would be very nice if somebody would help me.

Comment: Which video conference program do you use? Based on the system spec I would assume the Corei7 is a bit older, which model is it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Generic advice:

- Get a cooling mat. Laptops often have sub-optimal cooling.
- Alternatively open it up and clean out fans as they get clogged up.
- If you are confident enough find your manufacturer service manual and dismantle your laptop and replace the thermal compounds.

Searching Google for [https://www.google.com/search?q=elitebook+8540w+thermal+paste](https://www.google.com/search?q=elitebook%208540w%20thermal%20paste) shows a good number of teardown, cleaning and paste replacement videos.

That is likely to be the best you can do without completely replacing the laptop. If you laptop is still underperforming then you need more RAM, a better processor, or both which would mean a new laptop. Processors are rarely replaceable.